# Change password with kpasswd via command line?

Tags: bash, bsd

I want to use kpasswd to change my password. Since I have to do it for multiple realms, I'd like to automate it passing on the password. I want to set a variable in bash and pass that on to kpasswd, somehow. :) Variable setting is no problem, but passing it on to kpasswd, that is an issue.

How would I do that?

From `man kpasswd` it seems that there isn't some flag which I can pass along, so I was thinking using printf or some other solution. Unfortunately this doesn't work:

```
printf "$PWD\n$PWD\n" | kpasswd $KERBEROS_USERNAME@DOMAIN
```

Some other details:

```
$ bash --version

GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin14)

$ kpasswd --version

kpasswd (Heimdal 1.5.1apple1)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is traditionally done with an `expect` script. Eg

```
    #!/usr/bin/expect --
    set user [lindex $argv 0]
    set oldpassword [lindex $argv 1]
    set password [lindex $argv 2]
    spawn kpasswd $user
    expect "password"
    send "$oldpassword\r"
    expect "password"
    send "$password\r"
    expect "password"
    send "$password\r"
    expect eof
```

Put this script in a file, say `mysetpw`, do `chmod +x mysetpw`, then run it with `./mysetpw principalname oldpassword newpassword`.  I don't have `kpasswd`, but the examples on the web seem to suggest it needs the old password too, as in this scipt. You may need to change the prompts (eg `"password"`) that the script looks for to know when it should send the next line.

Comment: Thanks a lot meuh! Will give it a try and post the results asap.

Comment: Works! Learned something today, about 'expect'. Didn't know that it existed, but this can be really useful!

Comment: notice that for Mac, you need to change the first expect to be Password (capital P) because of the different implementation. The rest works! thanks a lot!